# How to Kill Hadoop fs -copyToLocal task

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I ran the following command on my local filesystem:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal <HDFS Path>
```

But, in the middle of the task (after hitting the command in terminal and before the command completes it's task), I want to cancel the copy.  How can I do this ?

Also, is -copyToLocal executed as a MR job internally ? Can someone point me to a reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the FileSystem API to stream & copy the file to local. There is no MR.

You could find the process on the machine & kill the process. It is usually a JVM process which gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Nohup and/or & to perform the process you will get the job status by searching CopyToLocal in ps -eaf action, and if you are using normal command execution, you can use ctrl+z or ctrl+c. these will kill the process.

In Both case the dump and temp location which all create remains there, so once killing the process you have to clear the dump/temp dump to perform the same process again.

It will not create any MR Job,